# How do I assign task to Case Owners without breaking on a queue owned case?

Tags: process-builder, queue

Currently I have a process builder flow that is built to assign a task to the case owner when a case comment is added by someone other than the case owner. 90% of the time this works great, but when the case is owned by a queue rather than a user, my process builder breaks when attempting to assign the task, as it sees the queue id as an incorrect ID when expecting a user ID.

Given that this is a process builder and not an apex function, I am not sure if there is a good way to dynamically check each case and somehow differentiate between the owner being a queue vs the owner being a user. I had considered making another block on my process builder, one for assigning to user and one for assigning to queues, but I am not sure how to differentiate between them and I am also not sure if you can even assign a task to a queue at all.

Any help would be appreciated. I've posted a couple screenshots of the process builder below.

[image: Condition]

[image: Action]

Comment: You cannot assign a Task to a Queue. How would you address such situation? Would you assign the Task to a generic User?

Comment: I suppose if we cannot assign a task to a queue as I fear then we would probably like to give it to either the comment creator or just default user.

Comment: I have added an approach which should help you to identify a queue vs. an owner. Based on that, you can then assign the Task to whomever you choose. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign a Task to a Queue.

In your PB, if you can identify a Case that is still assigned to a Queue, then you can choose a different User altogether to whom the Task can be assigned. And this is what I understand is, you need a way to distinguish the owner type.

*I have limited experience around Process Builder*, but the below approach should help you to distinguish between the owner (queue vs. user) for a Case.

To identify an Owner if it's a Queue or an Owner, you can create a simple formula on your Case object and then utilize that formula in your PB to verify and take further steps accordingly. Your formula let's say is named as `IsOwnerQueue` which returns a type `checkbox`, the formula would be as:

```
Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = "<Your Queue Name>"
```

So if the Case is assigned to any Queue, this will always be `true`. And then in your PB, you could verify if the value of the field `IsOwnerQueue` is `true`, then assign the Task to another User.

You could use this field elsewhere if you need to verify the owner on the Case utilizing this field.

---

But, as David suggested in the comments, if you only need it on a PB, then you can utilize the condition to verify if `Owner Id Starts with 500`, thus signifying that the Owner is a User without the change on the Object.

Comment: That will work, but you can also just look at the OwnerId in Process Builder Criteria to see if it "Starts With '500'" (=> User) to avoid making data model changes.

Comment: That's a better approach I would say. I just don't have much experience with PB, so didn't know if there's a way to identify it right there.

Comment: I have added your comment as another option.

Comment: Thanks guys this is super helpful and exactly the kinda thing I am looking for!